# Determine Eigenvalues and Eigenfunktions of Ingtegral Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let

$\displaystyle \left ( Af\right )(x)=\int_0^1 u(x)w(y)f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y$.

I want to compute eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of this operator in $L^2([0,1])$ where $u,w$ are continuous functions.

Since I just recently learned about the spectral theorem for compact symmetric operators and have no idea about any slightly more sophisticated theorems, I am not even sure, if I can solve this elementarily at all.

However, I could solve the simplest eigenvalue problems just using an ansatz like this

$\displaystyle Af = zf = \int_0^1 u(x)w(y)f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y,\ z\in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: It looks like the simple problem at the end that you say you can solve is the same as the first problem you are asking about.

Comment: This is not what i meant or wrote. I have been able to solve the simplest ev problems, but not this.

Comment: I understand and want to reformulate: I need a hint for this problem, as I am not able to progress.

Comment: Is your last equation supposed to be a first-step in solving the problem? (It would indeed be a correct first step)

Comment: Yes, it is. This step is quite trivial, however. I suspect, that I will eventually get a differential equation.

Comment: I think you are trying to make this problem harder than it is.  Just pull $u(x)$ out of the integral and you are essentially done.

Comment: I just cannot see how I would be done then, since $u(x),w(x)$ are arbitrary.

Comment: I assume that $u(x)$ and $w(x)$ are given to you.  So your operator takes a general function $f(x)$ and maps it to a new function $u(x)\int_0^1 w(y)f(y)dy$. There are only certain functions $f$ that satisfy $\lambda f(x) = u(x) \int_0^1 w(y)f(y)dy$ for all $x$, and these are the eigenfunctions (with corresponding eigenvalues).  The eigenfuntions/eigenvalues indeed depend on the particular given $u(x), w(x)$ functions.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem, I can not determine which eigenfunctions or eigenvalues. I simply don't know how to proceed from there on.

Comment: Guess a function and fill in a $\lambda$ that works.